# Kullback Leibler and Kakutani-Hellinger distance - deriving an inequality

Tags: probability-distributions, metric-spaces, information-theory

I am stuck with an exercise on the relation between KL and Kakutani-Hellinger distance, i.e. the objective is to show
$$K(P,\tilde{P}) \geq -2\log(1-\rho^2(P,\tilde{P}))$$
wherein $K$ denotes the KL-"distance" defined via $$E_P(\log(z))$$ (z denoting the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $dP$ with respect to $d\tilde{P}$assuming $dP << d\tilde{P}$)
and wherein the term $(1-\rho^2(P,\tilde{P}))$ denotes the Hellinger integral $$E_{\tilde{P}}\left(\sqrt{z}\right).$$

This boils down to showing the following:
$$E_{\tilde{P}}\left(z \log(z)\right) \geq -2\log E_{\tilde{P}}\left(\sqrt{z}\right)$$

I need to employ an appropriate inequality between these functions - but I have yet no idea on how to specify an appropriate relation.

Comment: Hint: for $Z = \mathrm{d}P/\mathrm{d}Q,$ $\mathbb{E}_Q[\sqrt{Z}] = \mathbb{E}_P[1/\sqrt{Z}]$.

Comment: thanks! I got it with this hint.

Comment: Nice! Will you write (and accept) an answer below so that the next person that has this question finds a solution? Oh, and, as an aside, I think I first saw this trick in a proof of the Bretagnolle-Huber inequality, which might also be worth checking out.

Comment: How do I accept the answer - there is no button because it is given in a comment. But maybe I didn't see it.

Comment: Write it in the answer box. With enough details.